# Simulate Firefox android on Windows

Tags: android, firefox, emulation

I need to debug a problem that seems to happen specifically on firefox android - problem doesnt happen on the Windows version of Firefox. I beleive there may be a javascript error causing this problem so I need to have debug acess to the developer console to see whats going on.

I played around with Fennec and also User Agent Switcher - http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/features/ extension in firefox, but neither one seems to help much.

Can anyone suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Run firefox in gennymotion or Android emulator?  Agent Switcher will find bugs related to bad data from the server, but won't find bugs related to the browser's platform specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan. I will look into both options.

Comment: You can install the firefox apk on the android emulator. Create a virtual device similar to the one you're trying on, and then run it. Look at the LOGCAT or attach ADB and see what you find.

Comment: i added the answer ;) same text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the firefox apk on the android emulator. Create a virtual device similar to the one you're trying on, and then run it. Look at the LOGCAT or attach ADB and see what you find.

Comment: Thanks guys. Apprecaite the quick response